# CodeMirror: How add tables to sql-hint?

Tags: autocomplete, codemirror

I can't figure how add tables to codemirror. I have sql-hint.js included, and work for keywords but don't understand how add tables and columns...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sadly, this does not appear to be documented anywhere.

With some trial and error I was able to figure out that you can pass in a structure of table and column names as options when invoking the hinter, like this:

```
CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete = function(cm) {
    CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.sql, { 
        tables: {
            "table1": [ "col_A", "col_B", "col_C" ],
            "table2": [ "other_columns1", "other_columns2" ]
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I know that this question is somewhat old but..I found an interesting way, valid in 4.3 release (I don't know anything about older releases): Just add the "CodeMirror.hint.sql" value (without quotes, as its a function) as "hint" option and add the "tables" object as a sub-object defined in "hintOptions" object.

Something like:

```js
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0], {
        mode: "text/x-sql",
        extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}, // To invoke the auto complete
        hint: CodeMirror.hint.sql,
        hintOptions: {
            tables: {
                "table1": [ "col_A", "col_B", "col_C" ],
                "table2": [ "other_columns1", "other_columns2" ]
            }
        }
});
```

That's it. Note that the "extraKeys" is absolutely not needed, but I found it to be great to test the autocomplete more easily. =)

Good luck. :)

Comment: The problem is that this only works without quotes. Once I enter `"tabl`, hit CTRL+Space, and choose `table1`, it ends up as `"tabltable1`. Even worse, I correct it to `"table1".` and then autocomplete is not able to propose `"col_A"`....

Comment: Hello, I'm newbie here. I tried this on codemirror version 5.60.0, it seems like table columns aren't shown. Maybe the syntax has changed